# Why doesn't Internet Explorer show foreignObject?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js

I'm using d3js to make a tree and need to insert foreignObject but Internet Explorer doesn't show it

```
node.append('g:foreignObject')
    .attr('width', rectWidth)
    .attr('height', rectHeight)
    .attr('x', rectWidth / -2)
    .attr('y', rectHeight / -2)
    .append('xhtml:p')
    .html(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported (and looks like it won't be), see https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/812053/ie12-feature-request-add-support-for-the-foreignobject-svg-element.

Comment: You could use HTML on top of the SVG and position appropriately.

Comment: I am the "Rick Godwin" comments in that link. It blows my mind how the MS IE team are so good at being so stupid for so long. My motto on this is "IE is a Foreign Object!".